# How can I Enable Webp support in php GD library in MAC

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I have installed PHP PHP 7.2.0beta3 using homebrew.
The `phpinfo` shows that the webmp support is enabled,
[image]

But when i try to convert an image using a [wrapper class](https://github.com/rakibtg/PHP-ImageToWebp) it shows this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagewebp() in /Users/rakibtg/Projects/PHP-ImageToWebp/ImageToWebp.php:37 Stack trace ...

How I can enable webp support as well in macOS using homebrew php installed environment?

Comment: Where do you see WebP on that list? WBMP ≠ WebP.

Comment: Yes thats what i have asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
brew reinstall php72 --with-webp
```

Or, failing that, try:

```
brew rm php72
brew install webp
brew install php72 --with-webp
```

---

In general, you can find the options available for any given package with:

```
brew options <PACKAGENAME>
```

For example:

```
brew options homebrew/php/php72
```

**Sample Output**

```
--with-argon2
    Include libargon2 password hashing support
--with-cgi
    Enable building of the CGI executable (implies --without-fpm)
--with-debug
    Compile with debugging symbols
--with-enchant
    Build with enchant support
--with-gmp
    Build with gmp support
--with-homebrew-curl
    Include Curl support via Homebrew
--with-homebrew-libressl
    Include LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL via Homebrew
--with-homebrew-libxml2
    Include Libxml2 support via Homebrew
--with-homebrew-libxslt
    Include LibXSLT support via Homebrew
--with-httpd
    Enable building of shared Apache Handler module
--with-imap
    Include IMAP extension
--with-libmysql
    Include (old-style) libmysql support instead of mysqlnd
--with-mssql
    Include MSSQL-DB support
--with-pdo-oci
    Include Oracle databases (requries ORACLE_HOME be set)
--with-pear
    Build with PEAR
--with-phpdbg
    Enable building of the phpdbg SAPI executable
--with-postgresql
    Build with postgresql support
--with-thread-safety
    Build with thread safety
--with-webp
    Build with webp support
--without-bz2
    Build without bz2 support
--without-fpm
    Disable building of the fpm SAPI executable
--without-ldap
    Build without LDAP support
--without-legacy-mysql
    Do not include the deprecated mysql_ functions
--without-libsodium
    Build without libsodium support
--without-mysql
    Remove MySQL/MariaDB support
--without-pcntl
    Build without Process Control support
--without-unixodbc
    Build without unixODBC support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Comment: it does not work anymore, can't use webp on php 7.1.31 and i don't know how to enable it

Comment: @AmauryLeproux Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529784/2836621

Comment: hum i couldn't rm my versions nor use PECL without sudo and even trying with sudo it failed. And WEBP is still not known as function :/