# How to enable Webp for PHP 7 and MAMP

Tags: php, webp

So my error is

> Call to undefined function imagewebp()

I tried this command `brew reinstall php72 --with-webp`, but it does not work anymore.

I don't know where and how I should change my conf file.

If you have an idea, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Enable Webp support in php GD library in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467053/how-can-i-enable-webp-support-in-php-gd-library-in-mac)

Comment: unfortunately no cause brew has removed every packages so I already tried this solution but does not fix this problem anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GD already is in mac, you don't need install it. update your homebrew and install webp manually. and after that php72

```
> brew update

> brew install webp
> brew reinstall php72 --with-webp
```

if not work try install without  --with-webp
how you install it manually maybe you don't need that parameter

```
> brew reinstall php72
```

and if all fail comment your osx version please.

Comment: I tried the commands the only one who does not work is brew reinstall php72 --with-webp, the result is "Error: invalid option: --with-webp" | my oxs version is Catalina 10.15.12 and php version is still 7.1

Comment: I did and i enabled php so php -v gives "PHP 7.2.26 (cli)" but the function imagewebp still does not work for some reason :/

Comment: but when you install with the command brew install webp it didn't sho an error so you must include in php.ini the library

Comment: yes when I run "brew install webp" the installation works. What should I add to the php.ini ? --with-webp-dir ? --with-webp-dir=DIR ?

Comment: it seems to work now that I updated everything and add "-with-webp-dir=DIR" to the php.ini thank you Emiliano

Comment: @AmauryLeproux, can you post how you did it ? Because it's unclear to me.

Answer (score -1):

You should have the `GD` extension enabled: `extension=gd2` in your `php.ini`.
To find out where your ini files are you can either use `phpinfo` in an script or use `php --ini` in cli to get its configs.

Comment: I just added "extension=gd2" in my php.ini, restart mamp but still get "Call to undefined function imagewebp()" :/

Comment: ping @CodeSpirit